# How do I access data from an external file in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Still new to Vue.js, but very much enjoying to learn about it. Before I get to using Axios and Vuex store I'd like to understand how can I send some test data from a separate file to my component? Hope someone can help.

If I do this within my component it works:

```
<script>

export default {
    data () {
        return {
        logItems: [
            { log1d: 1, logDetail: 'This is some log detail for log 1', logType: 'general', createdBy: 'name', CreatedAt: 'date' },
            { log1d: 2, logDetail: 'This is some log detail for log 2', logType: 'general', createdBy: 'name2', CreatedAt: 'date2' },
            { log1d: 3, logDetail: 'This is some log detail for log 3', logType: 'general', createdBy: 'name3', CreatedAt: 'date3' },
            { log1d: 4, logDetail: 'This is some log detail for log 4', logType: 'general', createdBy: 'name4', CreatedAt: 'date4' }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But I assumed I could import it as follows from an external file:

```
import logs from '~/components/testdata.vue'
export default {
    data () {
        return {
        logitems: logs
        }
    }
}
```

And in my testdate.vue file I have:

```
<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {

        // Dummy Test Data
        logs: [
            { log1d: 1, logDetail: 'This is some log detail for log 1', logType: 'general', createdBy: 'name', CreatedAt: 'date' },
            { log1d: 2, logDetail: 'This is some log detail for log 2', logType: 'general', createdBy: 'name2', CreatedAt: 'date2' },
            { log1d: 3, logDetail: 'This is some log detail for log 3', logType: 'general', createdBy: 'name3', CreatedAt: 'date3' },
            { log1d: 4, logDetail: 'This is some log detail for log 4', logType: 'general', createdBy: 'name4', CreatedAt: 'date4' }
            ]
        }
        return logs
    }
}
```

Is anyone able to tell me what am I doing wrong and why putting my data into a separate file doesn't work, please?

Many thanks.

Comment: What is displayed when you `console.log` your existing import? If I'm not mistaken when you require a `.vue` Component the resulting data property is accessible as a static reference usually within something simmilar to `logs.data().logs` in your case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you import any file, webpack uses an appropriate `loader` (specified in your `webpack.config.js`) to build the file. In case it is a `.vue` file, it uses `vue-loader` to build the file and return a Vue component. You need an Array containing your data, not a vue component. You can import simple `.js` and `.json` files for this.

Instead of importing a `.vue` file. you can just import `.json` or `.js` file.

**data.js**

```
const data = [{ log1d: 1, logDetail: 'This is some log detail for log 1', logType: 'general', createdBy: 'name', CreatedAt: 'date' },
            { log1d: 2, logDetail: 'This is some log detail for log 2', logType: 'general', createdBy: 'name2', CreatedAt: 'date2' },
            { log1d: 3, logDetail: 'This is some log detail for log 3', logType: 'general', createdBy: 'name3', CreatedAt: 'date3' },
            { log1d: 4, logDetail: 'This is some log detail for log 4', logType: 'general', createdBy: 'name4', CreatedAt: 'date4' }
            ]
export default data;
```

**component.vue**

```
import logs from 'data.js'
export default {
    data () {
        return {
        logitems: logs
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer op's post.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: how can i proceed if i have to use "this" inside array to get translations for example?

Comment: @delueg can give me an example? i don't get exactly how you are planning to use "this" inside array.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta i managed to get it work with mixins. Thanks. I wanted to access "this[in context of vue]" in order to set values to the array

Comment: You have to stick with either `data` or `logs` in both files.

Comment: @untill actually you dont since it is a default export. Although it is probably a good idea to stick to one thing.

Answer (score 3):

### Explainations

If you are using Vue template files, you can use the script tag src's attribute just like you would normally do with any other scripts in your HTML page.

Since Webpack is doing some special stuff when you import a Vue template file, for instance `example.vue`, you have to explode your configuration to extract the JavaScript part, that should not be compiled by the `vue-loader`.

### Example

`index.vue`

```
<template><!-- ... --></template>
<script src='index.js'></script>
<style scoped>/* ... */</style>
```

`index.js`

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      //...
    };
  }
};
```

`something.js`

```
import stuff from '../stuff/index.js';

export default {
  data() {
    return ...stuff.data();
  }
};
```

### Online Example

[image: Edit Vue Template]

### External Resources

See [What-About-Separation-of-Concerns](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#What-About-Separation-of-Concerns)

Comment: This is what I was referring to in the comments, this is generally how you would go about importing external data from a `.vue` component.

Answer (score 0):

I personally do it in the following way:

> data.js

```
export default {
  Variables...
}
```

> WebPage.vue

```
import { default as data } from "./data";
export default{
 data(){
  return data;
 }
}
```